# Xcode Instruments Allocations Overall Bytes Too Large

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments

I have completed my first iOS app. Its parsing and an rss feed and showing titles, date, creator name and images in a tableview. Now i am trying to check its performance before submitting it for the approval. I am using Xcode instruments for the very first time. I have first checked and removed all the leaks and now there are no memory leaks in the app. Now i am using Allocations. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Since i am using it for the very first time i am not sure about many things. Overall Bytes looks too large to me and i need to ask whether is there any limit or not which i can use? and should i look for overall bytes or live bytes or anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall bytes includes those that have been released and is a running total of what has been allocated to your app during the lifetime of the app. The Live Bytes is the one to really worry about as that is the one that shows bytes that are currently allocated.

Overall bytes could keep going on forever as long as you release stuff and the Live Bytes doesn't go too high then you will have no problems.

From that screenshot live bytes looks ok.

There are more details here [XCode Instruments Allocations: Look at Live Bytes or Overall Bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574364/xcode-instruments-allocations-look-at-live-bytes-or-overall-bytes?rq=1)